# printing 2 different times using only one instance variable in java

Tags: java

this is what it prints to me 

The hour of the first Time2 object is: 18

The minute of the first Time2 object is: 33
The hour of the second Time2 object is: 0
The minute of the second Time2 object is: 55

could someone please explain to me why the second hour is 0 ?
and almost forgot to mention that i can only use one instance variable

```
public class Time2
{
private int _minFromMid;
private final int _defaultVal = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Time2 firstTime = new Time2(18, 33);
    Time2 secondTime = new Time2(firstTime);

    System.out.println("The hour of the first Time2 object is: " + 
     firstTime.getHour());
    System.out.println("The minute of the first Time2 object is: " + 
    firstTime.getMinute());


    secondTime.setHour(16);
    secondTime.setMinute(55);

    System.out.println("The hour of the second Time2 object is: " + 
    secondTime.getHour());
    System.out.println("The minute of the second Time2 object is: " + 
    secondTime.getMinute());
  }

public Time2( int h , int m)
{     

    if(h > 23 || h < 0)
        h = _defaultVal;
    if(m > 59 || m < 0)
        m = _defaultVal;

    _minFromMid = (h * 60) + m;

}

public Time2(Time2 other)
{
    if(other != null)
        _minFromMid = other._minFromMid;

}

public int getHour()
{

    return _minFromMid / 60;

}

public int getMinute()
{

    return _minFromMid % 60;

}

public void setHour(int num)
{   

    if(num > 59 || num < 0)
        num = _defaultVal;

    _minFromMid = num;

}

public void setMinute(int num)
{

    if(num > 59 || num < 0)
        num = _defaultVal;

    _minFromMid = num;

}



public String toString()
{

    return Integer.toString(_minFromMid / 60) + ":" + 
    Integer.toString(_minFromMid % 60);

}

}
```

Comment: Copy&paste error: your `setHour` method sets the minute. Use a debugger to see what happens when you have such a situation again.

Comment: setMinutes() sets minFromMid to 55. getHours() returns 55 / 60, which is 0.

Comment: so any clue to fixing it using the same variables please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function called setHour and setMinute are wrong, it should be like:

```
public void setHour(int num)
{       
    if(num > 23 || num < 0)
        num = _defaultVal;

    _minFromMid = (num*60)+_minFromMid % 60;
}

public void setMinute(int num)
{

    if(num > 59 || num < 0)
        num = _defaultVal;

    _minFromMid = num + (_minFromMid/60)*60;

}
```

However, I suggest you to use two variables, one to store the hour and another to store the minutes. After that you will need to implement a function like getMinutesFromMid.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer !
i had to use only 1 instance variable because of schoolwork.